# Cannot destroy Twitter stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to use NPM twitter with Socket.io. The stream.destory() function is not working.

```
var util = require('util');
var twitter = require('twitter');
var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

var currentTwitStream;
hashtags = [];
module.exports = function (io) {
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A new user connected!');
    socket.on('data', function(data){
      hashtags.push('#' + data.hashtag);
      hashtags.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
      });
          if(currentTwitStream) currentTwitStream.destroy();

          twit.stream('statuses/filter',{track:hashtags.join(',')},function(stream){
            currentTwitStream = stream;
            stream.on('data',function(data,err){
              socket.emit();
              console.log(data.text);
            });
          });
    });
  });
};
```

I would be grateful for any feedback on how to fix this issue.

Comment: What does `not working` mean?

Comment: It is not destroying the stream @loganfsmyth

Comment: As in it keeps emitting data? Just looking for a bit more info.

Comment: Yer it keeps emitting data and the connection continues to stream - the Twitter API only allows for one stream and therefore it needs to be closed and opened when a client emits a new hashtag to track in addition to the previous ones. @loganfsmyth

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me to destroy the stream.

```
var clientSteam = {};

clientSteam = stream;// After your stream.on('data',function(data,err){
```

//Now To Destroy stream

```
if (Object.keys(clientSteam).length != 0)
        setTimeout(closeStream, 1000); 

function closeStream(){
    console.log('Closing stream...');
    clientSteam.destroy();
}
```